# How to get count record in hbase table? which is fastest way to query the record?

Tags: hive, hbase, bigdata

I have 100 Million record in HBase table. I have created hive external table.

How to query the record fastest way.

Hive --->  Select count(*) from table.

Running Query more than 8 hours.

Please guide me

Comment: what version of CDH you are using Balaji ?  ....assuming that you are using Cloudera on the basis of your comments on other answers

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way here would be use Hbase in built **RowCounter** operation which internally runs a map reduce job to count the number of rows.

Syntax:

`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter mytable`

Comment: well then I don't think there is any better way to get the counts. One reason why this might be taking a lot of time is that your cluster is very small.

Comment: The above command has given the **count of 11 million in around one min**. So there is something wrong with the cluster or usage. Using map reduce is the best way to perform count in Hbase.

Comment: Exactly because RowCounter internally is running a map reduce job only and there can't be a more efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports COUNT() query directly-
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`

But it will get slow as your records increases because hive uses MapReduce jobs. If you want to query really fast, I would recommend you using [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) or ORM tool [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera)